# Slick foreign key on two columns

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, slick-2.0

I using slick with postgres and I have the following two table:

```
class Friendships(tag: Tag) extends Table[Friendship](tag, "FRIENDSHIP") {
    def userOneId = column[Long]("USER_ONE")
    def userTwoId = column[Long]("USER_TWO")
    def blocked = column[Boolean]("BLOCKED", O.Default(false))
    def createdAt = column[Timestamp]("CREATED_AT")
    def * = (userOneId, userTwoId, blocked, createdAt) <>(Friendship.tupled, Friendship.unapply)
}


class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {
    def id = column[Long]("USER_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def firstName = column[String]("FIRST_NAME", O.NotNull)
    def lastName = column[String]("LAST_NAME", O.NotNull)
    def phone = column[String]("PHONE_NUMBER", O.NotNull)
    def lat = column[Double]("LATITUDE", O.NotNull)
    def long = column[Double]("LONGITUDE", O.NotNull)
    def updatedAt = column[Timestamp]("UPDATED_AT")
    def createdAt = column[Timestamp]("CREATED_AT")
    def * = (id.?, firstName, lastName, phone, lat, long, updatedAt, createdAt) <>(User.tupled, User.unapply)
}
```

`I'd like to know what happens if I do not have a primary key like in the Friendships table?`

More importantly, I'd like to know how to create a compound primary key on `userOneId` and `userTwoId` as foreign keys to the `id` field in the `Users` table, and set up a foreign key constraint so that when either `userOneId` or `userTwoId` is deleted, the friendship record gets deleted.

Thanks :)

Comment: I can't answer how to specifically do that in Slick, as such just adding a more general comment. One way to solve the problem more generally would be to use a surrogate key however, and the use of a surrogate key has other advantages also in this situation, such as evolution of the friendship table over time.

Comment: Not sure whether this helps or not in your case: you can also define unique constraints by using `index("unique_relationship", (userOneId, userTwoId), unique = true)`